# MySQL Fulltext rank rows higher if keyword exists, but not part of the search terms

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to tweak a full text (boolean) query. Is it possible to rank a row higher if a term is contained in a row, but *not* use that term as part of the search query?

So I'd like to rank a row higher if it contains the keyword cheese, but not actively search for the term cheese?

Currently I use something along the lines of `searchterm >cheese*`, but I believe that will still actually search for the term `cheese` also?

The problem this creates is if there are no results, it'll still show results based on `cheese`. I only want it to be used as a method of improving results, but not as something to be searched against.

`black >cheese*` might return rows that don't contain black in any way at all, but do contain the word cheese.

Comment: Do you mean setting it in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: You should use % for wildcards.

Comment: I mean in the `against` section for matching. Ghigo, this is fulltext not like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `+test cheese`. Documentation states that the results must contain `test` but if they also contain `cheese` they are ranked higher.

An example query:

```
SELECT 
  MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+test cheese' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance, 
  t.* 
FROM 
  test AS t 
WHERE 
  MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+test' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

You can check it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e5f8/4

Documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: This is much better than I had before, I'm getting some great results with it now, thanks!